# Adding frontend and backend URL to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Name

Tags: product, adminhtml, backend

I am trying to add both an ahref link to the backend order view + the frontend store view (items grid) @ `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Name`. This is not working; some small things that are boggling me.

- How can we retrieve the frontend url? (the problem is you have to detect what store it was sold in + build the URL)
- How can we retrieve the backend URL to directly edit (and see) the product
- Suppose it is a simple product: how would we then retrieve the same as above; only this time with the parent information (if it exists ... we probably need to add some HasParent() information)

The end link would look something like this

```
<a href="linktorightfrontendproduct">online: getSKU</a> (if has parent show parent link)

<a href="linktobackendproduct">online: getSKU</a>

<a href="linktorightfrontendPARENTproduct">parent link: getSKU</a> (if has parent show parent link)
```

Greatly appreciate your insights

Answer (score 0):

This is what we have so far: at least it is a start

Working

- shows backend edit url of (parent) configurable
- show frontend link, via workaround and using search

Not working yet

- show frontend link directly to the product (not via search)
- show backend edit url of child item (if it exists) for this order_item

Code so far

HELP WELCOME!

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Name
 */
?>

<?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()): ?>

<?php
  $productUrl = Mage::getUrl() . $_item->getProductUrl();
  $productSku = $_item->getSku();
  $productId  = $_item->getProductId();
  $storeId = $_item->getStoreId();
  $adminUrl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $productId));
  $frontendUrl = "https://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={$productSku}";
?>    

    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo "SKU:{$productSku} "; ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
    <div>
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" href="<?php echo $frontendUrl; ?>" target="_blank">view online</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" href="<?php echo $adminUrl; ?>" target="_blank">backend edit</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello snh_nl, instead of putting your clarification as an answer, please edit the question itself and put it there.